# Working with legacy code, is this a bad mock Controller? (security-wise especially)

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller

I'm used to the MVC structure of web apps, but while working with legacy code, I wasn't able to implement it exactly as it should be done. Mainly I can't pull in a router/controller components, and will have to do it by scratch. I was wondering if this kind of "controller" is bad for security, or what other flaws it has. Will it work in a pinch? (maintainability/scalability is not a big issue right now)

```
<?php

require '../app/bootstrap.php';

class SomeController
{
    private $foo;    

    public function bar()
    {
        //code
    }

    public function baz()
    {
        //code
    }

}

require '../app/bootstrap.php';

$controller = new SomeController;

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $method = $_POST['action'];

    // switch statement to make sure method is a certain string
    switch ($method) {
        case 'bar':
            $controller->bar();
            break;
        case 'baz':
            $controller->baz();
            break;

        default:
            $response = 'You do not have access to that page';
            break;
    }
}
```

It works by having an AJAX request sent to it with a $_POST['action'] variable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This should be asked on Code Review exchange, unless there's a specific problem you have that needs to be addressed.

Comment: This question is more of a code-review, so better be in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ahh thanks. I'll post it there.

Comment: @Dekel This code would be closed on CodeReview for being hypothetical